# Is possible generics can be used in swagger's dataType attribute?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I want to use generic at swaager's dataType attribute and the result is that the swagger page can also show the example of json params and json response.like this
[image: The correct show result in swagger]

I have found some answer about this to use generic like this ***GenericType«Array«byte»»***
here's my code

```java
@ApiOperation(value = "", notes = "insert", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "entity", value = "insert", required = true, dataType = "«T»", paramType = "body")
    })
    @PostMapping(value = "",params = "entity")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public T insert(@Valid @Validated @RequestBody T entity) {
        return service.insert(entity);
    }
```

but it's not working on the swagger,and show empty example
[image: empty result when use «T»]